# django unicode encode/decode errors

Tags: django, unicode, internationalization

My site needs to be able to serve data in different languages. I set it so it uses utf-8 and the db settings are set to that as well. I've been getting different different unicode errors over the admin.

For example:

1. In the admin list, when a field from the list contains a non ascii char. (i get UnicodeDecodeError)
2. When adding a new entry, a UnicodeEncodeError if the **unicode** method for the model returns an utf-8 decode (which fixes #1).
3. When using a filter_horizontal in the admin, if data from the used model contains non ascii chars, then the filter disappears from the form.

If I set the **unicode** method for the model to return for example:

```
return u'%s' % unicode(self.tag)
```

That seems to fix #1 and #2, but then that's when I get #3.

I have been looking a lot for a solution, but can't find something that fixes all different errors. What's the best way to deal with those?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode
...
def __unicode__(self): 
    return smart_unicode(self.tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is noteworthy that you can bypass unicode by simply encoding your data in hexadecimal before storing it in your database.

Something like this is sufficient

`MyModel(name=name.encode('hex'), password=password).save()`

You can then execute `name.decode('hex')` to return the data back to its former representation.