# Extract tweets json file to csv file Python

Tags: python, json, csv

I've got the json file from twitter API, the json looks like this:

```
{"in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, "geo": null, "id": 100689407677440000, "lang": "en", "in_reply_to_user_id": null, "contributors": null, "source": "<a href=\"https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck\" rel=\"nofollow\">TweetDeck</a>", "place": null, "user": {"profile_background_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/512692008/Screen_shot_2012-01-11_at_11.58.58_PM.png", "id_str": "181218735", "profile_link_color": "0084B4", "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000007522671/f4552422d443160c075fb3d521ffb3c2_normal.jpeg", "default_profile": false, "id": 181218735, "name": "Author Al King", "contributors_enabled": false, "is_translation_enabled": false, "profile_use_background_image": true, "friends_count": 109, "notifications": false, "utc_offset": -14400, "statuses_count": 3521, "listed_count": 3, "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", "default_profile_image": false, "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/512692008/Screen_shot_2012-01-11_at_11.58.58_PM.png", "profile_text_color": "333333", "description": "Order your eBook copy of the Truth-Selling LET IT BE KNOWN at http://t.co/9m4DBuSatZ", "time_zone": "Eastern Time (US & Canada)", "geo_enabled": false, "follow_request_sent": false, "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", "favourites_count": 1, "lang": "en", "verified": false, "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000007522671/f4552422d443160c075fb3d521ffb3c2_normal.jpeg", "followers_count": 117, "screen_name": "LetItBeKnownAKP", "url": "http://t.co/zl3wbvRpco", "is_translator": false, "profile_background_tile": true, "has_extended_profile": false, "following": false, "created_at": "Sat Aug 21 16:25:13 +0000 2010", "protected": false, "location": "", "entities": {"description": {"urls": [{"expanded_url": "http://www.thealkingpointofview.com", "display_url": "thealkingpointofview.com", "url": "http://t.co/9m4DBuSatZ", "indices": [62, 84]}]}, "url": {"urls": [{"expanded_url": "http://www.thealkingpointofview.com", "display_url": "thealkingpointofview.com", "url": "http://t.co/zl3wbvRpco", "indices": [0, 22]}]}}}, "truncated": false, "retweet_count": 0, "id_str": "100689407677440000", "retweeted": false, "created_at": "Mon Aug 08 22:06:40 +0000 2011", "favorited": false, "entities": {"urls": [], "hashtags": [{"text": "LETITBEKNOWNLIVERADIO", "indices": [14, 36]}], "user_mentions": [], "symbols": []}, "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "coordinates": null, "favorite_count": 0, "is_quote_status": false, "text": "WED at 8pm on #LETITBEKNOWNLIVERADIO our Discussion \"Violence among the YOUTH PT 2..... Bullying, Gang Violenc\u2026 (cont) http://deck.ly/~ZN88q", "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, "in_reply_to_screen_name": null}
```

what i do is extract only "id","lang","text" from above json, but when i load the json, error occurred, here is my code:

```
    import json
    with open ("tweet.json_test_1") as json_data:
    dataText = json.load(json_data)
    print (dataText)
```

the error is:
**ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 2836 - line 2 column 1 (char 2835 - 2868)**

sorry if this is a repeated question, i am new in python and ML. thanks

Comment: Thx, that is what i thought before, yes, it is loads of JSON objects, i tried to copy only one JSON in the tweet.json_test_1, and tried to use json.loads as well, but the error is: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'TextIOWrapper'

Comment: @HAOCHEN: the code in your question does not correspond to the error that does not correspond to the json data that you've shown. It makes it difficult to help you. [Create a standalone test (code + data)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post whatever error it produces (the full traceback). Limit your questions to one issue per question

Comment: THX,my mistake, i got the wrong json and i've fixed already.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `tweet.json_test_1` file has multiple JSON objects, one per line in fact, so you'd do better to read it line by line and load each JSON object as a string. I recommend using a `try except` to catch if some lines don't have JSON. But bear in mind this means that if you're getting no output then none of the lines contain valid JSON.

```
import json

with open ("tweet.json_test_1") as json_data:
    for line in json_data:
        try:
            dataText = json.loads(line)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        print (dataText)
        #Do other stuff here, especially if you want to retain all the JSON objects
```

Incidentally, if you're the one creating the `tweet.json_test_1` file then it's recommended to just put all the JSON objects in a list, and then `json.load` should work fine.

Comment: thanks, it worked, some of json loaded, but another error is  'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0251' in position 511: character maps to <undefined>, i noticed it was because the coding, the json i loaded was encode by the utf-8, is this problem?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that character is part of UTF-16. There's an answer for that error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27093194/4374739). That answer uses it on soup but you can just use it like this: `line.encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: :(  oops, not working, the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Comment: That shouldn't be happening, `encode` returns a string. Is this your full line of code: `dataText = json.loads(line.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: with open ('tweet_2.json') as json_data:
    for line in json_data:
        try:
            dataText = json.loads(line.encode('utf-8'))
        except ValueError:
            continue
        print (dataText)