# Beautiful Soup Unicode Encoding Error

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am getting this error while while I call soup.get_text() on a html doc in beautiful soup

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xa9' in position 2740: character maps to <undefined>
```

How do I debug such errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters)