# Python : UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2190' in position 2936

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, python-3.5

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Books\Python\gsearch.py", line 21, in <module>
  text_file.write(titles)
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
  return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2190' in position 2936: character maps to <undefined>
```

The line `text_file.write(titles)` is supposed to write some text stored in the `titles` variable to a file. I have read other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters) on Stackoverflow. However, they specifically deal with console output using `print`. I want to write the text to a file.

Comment: Briefly: when you open a file that contains or will contain Unicode characters, specify a Unicode encoding.

Comment: Also, I copy-pasted your question's exact title into a Google search, and the relevant duplicate was the fourth result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify a proper encoding for your file object at opening time. This can be done by passing the encoding to `encoding` keyword argument of `open()` function.

For example:

```
with open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf8') as text_file:
    pass
```