# Getting an error when reading file names in a drive

Tags: python-3.x, python-module

I've written a Python program which is supposed to do something straight forward and simple: read all the files in a C drive and create a spreadsheet containing just the files' names (I intend to make the program more complex later, so far I'm just in the first phase).

The problem I run into from time to time is that, while the program is scanning the C drive, runs into some files names (usually in Temp folders) that, for some reason, seem to be using a weird character that is not recognized by the program, and I get an error referring to the CP1252.

The problem is: my program worked fine in the computer I used first (my work computer), but it failed when I tried it home. My work computers uses Windows 7 32 bit, my home computer uses Windows 10 64 bit, but I've got the perception that the issue is not related to the OS.

```
import os
import csv

counter=0

wrkdir=os.getcwd()
logdir=wrkdir+"\\Logs"
resultfile=wrkdir+"/Logs/Report.csv"
with open(resultfile, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    reportwriter=csv.writer(csvfile)
    cdrive=("C:\\")
    for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(cdrive):
        path=str(dirName)
        for fname in fileList:
            name=str(fname)
            fullname=path+"\\"+fname
            reportwriter.writerow([fullname])
            counter=counter+1
            reportwriter.writerow(["Total number of files in C:/ ->",counter])
print ("Report created, "+str(counter)+" files detected.")
```

Does anyone know how can I get the program to work in any computer (at least, any computer running Windows) without a problem?

The error I get tend to look like this:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 224-225: character maps to

Comment: possible dupe of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters)

Comment: I've tried the .encode('utf-8') solution, but that seems to bring other trouble (namely, the escape "\" is then duplicated in the name of all files).

Comment: aren't you explicitly duplicating the escape character in this line? --> `fullname=path+"\\"+fname`