# Python Dictionary to csv file not working

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary, zendesk-api

Sorry for the duplicate title type.  I am having a problem finding and example on how to accomplish this.  I have a json file I'm pulling from Zendesk.  I'm doing a json.dumps to get that to a readable formation and in a python dictionary.  I have the following in a for loop so I can get just the info I need out of the json file and write it to a csv file.

```
for item in data['results']:
    print(
        item['id'] ,item['via']['channel'], item['via']['source']['from'], item['subject'], item['tags'],
        item['created_at'], item['status'], item['custom_fields'][12], item['custom_fields'][12]['value'],
        item['result_type'], item['priority']
```

from this code I get the items I want with the correct information.

I have tried the following to print this out to a file but all I get returned in the file is the last record

```
import csv

with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:

csv_app = csv.writer(file)
for item in python_data['results']:
    csv_app.writerows(item['id'], item['via']['channel'],item['via']['source']['from'],item['subject'], item['tags'],
           item['created_at'], item['status'], item['custom_fields'][12], item['custom_fields'][12]['value'],
           item['priority'], item['result_type'])
```

I would like to get some suggestions on how to get everything (i've tried alot of stuff)   Also there is an **item['via']['source']['from']['name']**  I have taken out due to it causing errors when there is no value there.  How do I handle this on a field by field basis I'm assuming a if condition.

Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you open many times to write data then you should open in `append` mode using `a` instead `w`

Comment: What happens when you do `writerow` instead of `writerows`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `file` is a reserved word in python.  Use something else such as `f` or `fout`.

Second, use `writerow` instead of `writerows`.

Third, your indentation is off in your example (last five lines should be indented one level).

```
import csv

data = {'results': [{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}, 
                    {'A': 10, 'B': 20, 'C': 30}]}
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    csv_app = csv.writer(f)
    for item in data['results']:
        csv_app.writerow([item[x] for x in ['A', 'B', 'C']])

$ cat test.txt
1,2,3
10,20,30
```

Comment: Perfect that you Alexander, I swear I have tried this same thing but the last line was the key, I'm able to get what I need out now.  Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Well almost worked,  I have a description field that can get quite large and don't know what's causing it but getting a unicodeEncodeError 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2502' in position 799: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters