# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character - Python Report CSS

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-unicode, weasyprint

I know this kind of question has been asked before but nothing worked for me.

I'm trying to generate some PDF report using `weasyprint`. Here is my code;

```
htmlContent = py_str["htmlContent"]

HTML(string=htmlContent).write_pdf(target=response,
        stylesheets=[CSS(string=getCSS())])
```

but it doesn't generate any PDF. On debugging I found out that issue is in this `getCSS()` function that returns css string. By print this funtion on console, I'm getting this error

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x91' in position 5042: character maps to <undefined>

this is CSS that I've from line number 5040 to 5042

```
.nav-pills > li {
   float: left;
 }
```

All solutions that I found out are related to `utf-8` but I could not understand where to use this `utf-8` in my code. I'm totally stuck here.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. I can add full css if needed.

**UPDATE**

I've tried using encoding("utf-8") in these ways;

```
HTML(string=htmlContent).write_pdf(target=response,
    stylesheets=[CSS(string=getCSS().encode("utf-8"))])
```

and then this one too

```
 HTML(string=htmlContent, encoding="utf-8").write_pdf(target=response,
    stylesheets=[CSS(string=getCSS())])
```

But no luck...

Comment: 5042 is not the line number but the position. You are looking in a wrong place.

Comment: ohh.. thank you for correction.. but how can I find out this position?

Comment: Read the file in Python and print the substring [5000:5100] or something like that.

Comment: @DyZ I couldn't find it.. but do you have any idea what could be the error or something that I'm missing here?

Comment: Try getting some luck [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters).

Comment: I've tried this one too but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who is facing this issue and nothing worked for you like me.. try disabling your extensions/ add-Ons of browsers. In my case, I've to uninstall IDM and my issue is gone. Now I need to find why it is not working with IDM. But for time being, my issue is resolved.