# Avoiding Python Unicode encoding errors on Travis CI

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, travis-ci

Using Python 3 to generate Unicode output in an [Travis CI Windows VM](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/windows/) produces errors such as

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03b2' in position 1532: character maps to <undefined>
```

Is there a way to configure Windows or Travis to avoid this?

Comment: Note that this is not a question about [how to change the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27093194/656912) to avoid the error, but how to configure Windows so that code that works on all other platforms works there.