# Writing unicode characters to file fails in PowerShell with Anaconda/Python

Tags: python, windows, powershell, anaconda

Just starting to use PowerShell on Windows 10 with the latest Anaconda3 and Python3.7 and cannot run the script due to encoding error. The script attempts to write a text file which contains some German characters and throws:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0144' in position 10: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have tried `chcp 65001` and setting `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` but this does not help. 
How does it work with PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a Python error not a Powershell error. If it was a Powershell issue, you'd get an exception that would look something like...

```
Attempted to divide by zero.
At line:1 char:1
+ 1/0
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Sabbir Ahmed gave a solution to this error (on Windows 10) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters) post. You probably have a line that looks something like...

```
with open('filename', 'w') as f:
  ...
```

Change it to...

```
with open('filename', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  ...
```

A-