# Simple Python loop problem, can't figure out proper answer

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to webscrape https://old.reddit.com/r/all/ and get the entries on the first page.

When I run my code, it works but for the post_text it only copies the last post on the reddit page 25 times. I know this is because its getting the entry and then posting it each time through the loop.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://old.reddit.com/r/all/'

request = urllib.request.Request(my_url,headers={'User-Agent': 'your bot 0.1'})
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
page_html = response.read()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

posts = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "top-matter"})
post = posts[0]

authors = page_soup.findAll("p", {"class":"tagline"})
author = authors[0]

filename = "redditAll.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "Title of the post, Author of the post\n"
f.write(headers)

for post in posts:
    post_text = post.p.a.text.replace(",", " -")

for author in authors:
    username = author.a.text

    f.write(post_text + "," + username + "\n")
f.close()
```

---

Changed this

```
for post in posts:
    post_text = post.p.a.text.replace(",", " -")

for author in authors:
    username = author.a.text
```

To that

```
for post, author in zip(posts, authors):
    post_text = post.p.a.text.replace(",", " -")
    username = author.a.text
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LTheriault is correct, but I'd consider this more idiomatic.

```
for post, author in zip(posts, authors):
    post_text = post.p.a.text.replace(",", " -")
    username = author.a.text

    f.write(post_text + "," + username + "\n")
```

Comment: I had a feeling I was missing a nicer way of doing but couldn't figure out what I was overlooking. This is definitely the best way of doing it, IMO.

Comment: I had no idea the 'zip' thing was a thing. Thank you so much.

Comment: "zip() should only be used with unequal length inputs when you don’t care about trailing, unmatched values from the longer iterables. If those values are important, use itertools.zip_longest() instead."
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: If you didn't know about zip you might not know about enumerate:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the two loops separately. In your code below, you're looping through each post and assigning a string to post_text, but doing nothing else with it. When that loop is done, post_text is the last thing it has been assigned as before it moves into the authors loop and writes a string with each author and the string you have stored in post_text.

```
for post in posts:
    post_text = post.p.a.text.replace(",", " -")

for author in authors:
    username = author.a.text

    f.write(post_text + "," + username + "\n")
```

Assuming that there are an equal number of elements in posts and authors, you should be able to fix it with the following:

```
for i in range(len(posts)):
    post_text = posts[i].p.a.text.replace(",", " -")
    username = authors[i].a.text

    f.write(post_text + "," + username + "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes so much sense. I knew the loop was incorrect but I've looking at it for so long I couldn't wrap my head around it.

Comment: I added your code in and I'm sure it'll work but now I'm getting `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\webscrape\reddit.py", line 34, in <module>
    f.write(post_text + "," + username + "\n")
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f60d' in position 195: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Someone else came across a similar issue with bs4, so hopefully there's an explanation for the particular issue there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters

Comment: Also, check out Keri's answer below. I personally think it's an even better way of handling the loop than what I gave. It's similar, but cleaner.

Comment: The new error is due to unicode characters in the post / author name. The top answer in  LTheriault's link should fix it

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're writing to the file object within the scope of the 
of the second for loop `for author in authors`, so you will indeed write the last value of `post_text` multiple times.

If you want to combine authors and posts you might zip them and them iterate over them (assuming they are the same length)

```
for author, post in zip(posts, authors):
    write.(f 'author: {author}, post: {post}')
```

I would also recommend to write to file using a context manager

eg.

```
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.write('stuff')
```

Comment: If you're not aware, this method of formatting text is called an f-string. It only works with python 3.6 or later.

`f.write.(f 'author: {author}, post: {post}')`