# UnicodeEncodeError Converting Requests Text to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape website but with certain searches it gives me error:

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 5399-5400: character maps to <undefined>
```

My Python script is:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.protocols.io/api/v3/protocols?filter=%20public%20&order_field=relevance&key=%20gel%22electrophoresis%20'

r = requests.get(url)
text = r.text 
jason = json.loads(text)
print (jason)
```

I have tried to change the encoding as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters) by

```
text = text.encode('utf-8')
```

But still recieve the same error. It seems to be using the cp1252 encoding not utf-8?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Update: 
This seems to be a issue in git bash or atom as works without error in Spyder or windows cmd

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is because you haven't imported sys,

like this:

```
import sys
import codecs

import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.protocols.io/api/v3/protocols?filter=%20public%20&order_field=relevance&key=%20gel%22electrophoresis%20'

r = requests.get(url)
text = r.text 
text = text.encode('utf-8') 
jason = json.loads(text)
print (jason)
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't seem to work for me. I still get the same error. What version of python are you using (I am on 3.7.4)

Comment: python 3.6.4 
i don't think is the version that disturbs

How are you running the codes?

Comment: i run mine on the terminal using this:
**python3 pytest.py**

Comment: I just updated to 3.8.3. I am running in atom text editor

Comment: I ran on terminal but still have same error! Would you mind sharing your output?

Answer (score 0):

My OUTPUT:
as you can see is a json of items

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is very wierd. I run in atom and terminal i get this error. I ran in Spyder (python 3.7) and it works, any ideas?

Comment: I am going to leave it open because I think the original code works without importing sys or codecs, and i need a solution that works on terminal or atom. Thanks for the help though