# unexpected result while parsing html with bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, python-unicode

i try this code in Python 3.8.2:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

html = urllib.request.urlopen(
    'https://vietnamnet.vn/').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").encode("utf-8")

print(soup.title)
```

but i received:

[image]

instead of expected: `<title>Báo VietNamNet - Tin tức online, tin nhanh Việt Nam và thế giới</title>`

what am i doing wrong and how can i fix it?

I have to use `.encode("utf-8")` because **html string** contains unicode character. Does it effect the **soup**?

Thanks!

Comment: `title` is a function, so you have to call the function: `print(soup.title())`, otherwise you get the function object itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `.encode()` on the parser you are assigning a byte string to soup. The parser is completely lost, as `.encode()` returns a byte string.

bs4 should handle the character set for you.

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.title)
```

Output:

```py
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib.request
>>> html = urllib.request.urlopen(
...     'https://vietnamnet.vn/').read()

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
>>> print(soup.title)
<title>Báo VietNamNet - Tin tức online, tin nhanh Việt Nam và thế giới</title>
>>>
```

Comment: can you try my code? because if i dont pass the .encode(), python raises this error: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u1ee9' in position 29: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: Yes the code works well for me, what version of Python are you using? I will edit my answer with my input/output.

Comment: i dont know what is going wrong? Im using Windows 10, python 3.8.2

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

html = urllib.request.urlopen(
    'https://vietnamnet.vn/').read().decode("utf-8")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

title = soup.title
print(title)
print(title.string)
```

You have to decode while reading.

Comment: i tried this but received this error: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u1ee9' in position 29: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: This is working for me (tried it on 3.8.2 also). Are you trying to write the data to a file? Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters

Answer (score -1):

After reading your url, you should be decoding it using the appropriate encoding format like below.

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

html = urllib.request.urlopen(
    'https://vietnamnet.vn/').read().decode('utf8')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
title = soup.find('title')

print("title is :", title)
```

Comment: i got this error while trying your code: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u1ee9' in position 29: character maps to <undefined>"