# how to resolve encoding errors in python?

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to parse a csv downloaded file from my bank account. The file gets opened with:

```
with open('umsatz.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
```

When trying to simply print the various entries I got the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\joajo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 13: character maps to <undefined>
```

Opening in notepad++ the problematic texts looks like:

```
LOHN-/GEHALTS�BERTRAGFREMDSPESE
```

Comment: Can you share your file somewhere (i.e. google drive)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I'm getting "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25b2' in position 84811: character maps to <undefined>" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62656579/why-im-getting-unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-u2)

Comment: Can your share your ```sys.stdout.encoding``` output? You can do so by ```import sys``` first.

Answer (score 1):

Just open in 'rb' format. Here the code:

```
with open('umsatz.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
     data = csv_file.read().decode('utf-8')
```