# PyCharm File size exceeds configured limit (2,56 MB), code insight features not available

Tags: file, pycharm, size

I'm working with some big txt files, (some around 3 GB), and whenever I have to check the txt files the message "File size exceeds configured limit (2.56 MB), code insight features not available" appear in the top of the file, I tried to change the file size by going to `Help->Edit` custom properties and then adding the next line of code in the file that opens

```
idea.max.content.load.filesize=500000
```

the problem is that even after closing and re-opening PyCharm the same message appears, do I need to do something else? just writing that line of code is enough to change the filesize?, it doesn't need to be run like a normal code? if so how can I run it since the option doesn't appear?

Comment: Do you need code insight? What kind of file is it? Extension, format?

Comment: the extension format of the text file is txt. I looked up how to change the size of the file that PyCharm normally operates, and I found that line of code that I wrote but doesn't seem to be working

Comment: The property you need to edit is `idea.max.intellisense.filesize`. However, it will cause an enormous drain on your memory and processor. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/file-idea-properties.html

Comment: in reality, I don't think I need it, I'm working with pre-trained word vectors for Spanish, the thing is that I need to clean the file because some of the words are from other languages, so I made a program to divide the file in smaller txt files, but its stops from an error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0144' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>" that's why I want to actually open the file and look for the words that causes this error, because its very likely that those words are not in spanish and that I have to delete them from the file

Comment: I don't mind if it takes more of my memory size most of it isn't in use anyway, and I can't open the files in notepad or words because of its size

Comment: idea.max.intellisense.filesize seems to work, I also rebooted my PC just in case and now the message of the file size doesn't appear

Comment: Regarding the error: [UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

instead of using the original line of code I used

```
idea.max.intellisense.filesize = new size in kB
```

also, I advise rebooting the Pc after adding that line of code in the window that appears after going to `Help->Edit` custom properties

Comment: Why would PyCharm need you to reboot your machine? That makes no sense.

Comment: sense or not, it just worked after the reboot and didn't work before it

Comment: Did you try restarting PyCharm?

Comment: yeah, but for some reason restarting PyCharm didn't make any change until I reboot the pc

Comment: It worked for me after restarting PyCharm