# i'm writing this program to print out the names of all mp3 files in a particular folder and it encounters this error message

Tags: python, python-unicode, pathlib

```
from pathlib import Path

song_folder = Path(r"C:\Users\Tito\Music\Songs\1")

for song in song_folder.glob("*.mp3"):
    print (song.name)

  File "c:\Users\Tito\Documents\VS code\music_sort4.py", line 10, in <module>
    print (file)
  File "C:\Users\Tito\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 132-133: character maps to <undefined>
```

the code prints out mp3 files, when it encounters this character ⭐️, it displays an error. what does it mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters)

Comment: not really, how do you know what encoding to use?

Comment: `python -X utf8 myprogram.py`