# Python tabulate not writing to text file correctly

Tags: python, tabulate

Am trying to tabulate a simple list into a text file formatted using `tabulate()`, `fancy_grid` format is what i want and it prints alright in the console, however upon writing to text file, I get the error below. Removing the argument `tablefmt='fancy_grid'` makes it write a simple table, but it isn't what I want. I have also tried using docx format but still get the same error

This is on a Windows environment.

Code

```
from tabulate import tabulate

l = [['{:<118}.'.format("Hassan"), 21, "LUMS"], ["Ali", 22, "FAST"], ["Ahmed", 23, "UET"]]
table = tabulate(l, headers=['Name', 'Age', 'University'], tablefmt='fancy_grid', showindex="always")

with open("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\kaita.txt", "w") as outf:
    outf.write(table)
os.startfile("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\kaita.txt", "print")
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Developement/Desktop Applications/GuiWithWx/Learn/Teach/runpython.py", line 160, in <module>
    outf.write(table)
  File "C:\Python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-150: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters

Comment: the link suggets to add `.encode("utf-8")`

Comment: @antoine, it works thanks a lot, you can write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add: `.encode("utf-8")`.

```
from tabulate import tabulate

l = [['{:<118}.'.format("Hassan"), 21, "LUMS"], ["Ali", 22, "FAST"], ["Ahmed", 23, "UET"]]
table = tabulate(l, headers=['Name', 'Age', 'University'], tablefmt='fancy_grid', showindex="always")

with open("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\kaita.txt", "w") as outf:
    outf.write(table.encode("utf-8"))
os.startfile("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\kaita.txt", "print")
```

credit: [UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters)

Answer (score 1):

I ran it under linux. it works.

[image]

I think the problem is not in `tabulate` but in writing to the file

You can try save file with `utf-8` file format:

```
import io
from tabulate import tabulate

l = [['{:<118}.'.format("Hassan"), 21, "LUMS"], ["Ali", 22, "FAST"], ["Ahmed", 23, "UET"]]
table = tabulate(l, headers=['Name', 'Age', 'University'], tablefmt='fancy_grid', showindex="always")

with io.open("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\kaita.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outf:
    outf.write(table)

os.startfile("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\kaita.txt", "print")
```

Comment: on Windows it works after the encoding. I have edited the question to indicate this.

Comment: @JohnnKaita I appended other solution for this situation. Always good if you have a choice)