# Is there a way i can write custom symbols / emojis onto a text file?

Tags: python, unicode

Code:

```
MyTextFile.write("⚡")
```

Error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u26a1' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

The emoji 1.4.2 library won't work here because what I am doing is getting some text data from a website and storing it in a text file, and some of the text has emojis.
I also don't want to use UTF-8 encoding because it will just turn the emojis into a bunch of text.

Comment: Encode the text first, then write it to a file. When you are ready to use it, decode it

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I cannot recreate your error because of an undefined variable name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters)

Comment: "I also don't want to use UTF-8 encoding".  You *always* encode text when writing to a file and UTF-8 support emojis (as well as UTF-16 and UTF-32).  "it will just turn the emojis into a bunch of text".  No, it will turn it into bytes, which is the job of an encoding. If you *decode* the bytes with the wrong encoding, *then* it doesn't look correct.  Read [this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html).

Comment: Are you using Windows, perhaps (whose default character encoding is 8-bit only, I think)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the encoding like:

```
   with open("/tmp/mytextfile", "w", encoding="utf-8") as mytextfile:
        mytextfile.write("⚡")
        mytextfile.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create the file object, specify the encoding you want to use rather than relying on the default.