# UnicodeEncodeError when reading text from WebElement with selenium plugin

Tags: python, selenium, unicode, codec

the goal with this script Is to scrape comments from posts on Instagram. The expected results Is the name, comment and profile link of the user that commented. But what I get Is this error to be precise, `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 60-61: character maps to <undefined>`.

Currently I'm using this command to pull the comment text which Is the only one causing issues.

```
comment = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/div[1]/ul/ul[{}]/div/li/div/div[1]/div[2]/span'.format(i)).get_attribute('textContent')
```

With that one It gives me an error, but If I replace the `.format` command and the `{}` with the number `1` It works. But I can't do that since It won't get the rest of the comments. It looks like this instead.

```
comment = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/div[1]/ul/ul[1]/div/li/div/div[1]/div[2]/span').get_attribute('textContent')
```

That works and does not raise an error. I'm aware of the fact that this Is loosely discribed, I just don't know what more to write. If you need more information just leave a comment and I'll do my best to provide It. Thanks.

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters ?

Comment: If you go on this post, https://www.instagram.com/reel/CS8Bzv7H78w/, open inspector mode and open the DOM. Then copy & paste in this xpath '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/div[1]/ul/ul[1]/div/li/div/div[1]/div[2]/span', you should be directed to the top comment. That Is the text that I want to pull but It Is raising an error.

Comment: @Bakax It does actually, I'm no longer getting the error. Thanks bro.