# Web Scraping with python I can't print my variable

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, django-views

In my Django project I use BeautifulSoup for web scraping.It works ut I can't print or slice it. When I try it give the error: **(I'm doing this on the views.py)**

> "UnicodeEncodeError 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u200e' in
> position 59: character maps to <undefined "

.  How can I print x variable?

```
    URL = link
    user_agent = getRandomUserAgent()
    headers = {"User-Agent": user_agent}

    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')



    mylist = soup.find_all("td", class_="a-size-base prodDetAttrValue")

    for x in mylist:
         print(x)
```

Comment: Can you add the full traceback? Which line is triggering the error?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Have a look at [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired data is not possible to pull by bs4 only because of dynamically loaded by JavaScript but grab using bs4 with selenium and It didn't throw `UnicodeEncodeError`

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
table=driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09N4ZL8NV')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
mylist = soup.find_all("td", class_="a-size-base prodDetAttrValue")

for x in mylist:
    print(x.get_text(strip=True))
```

**Output:**

```
13.3 Inches
‎1920 x 1200 pixels
‎1920 x 1200 Pixels
‎2.8 GHz core_i7_family
‎16 GB LPDDR4X
‎2.8 GHz
‎512 GB Flash Memory Solid State
‎Intel Iris Xe Graphics
‎Intel
‎Iris Xe Graphics
‎Bluetooth, 802.11ax
‎Lenovo
‎ThinkPad X13 Yoga Gen 2
‎20W80056US
‎PC
‎Windows 11 Pro
‎2.65 pounds
‎8.4 x 12 x 0.61 inches
‎8.4 x 12 x 0.61 inches
‎Black
‎Intel
‎1
‎DDR4 SDRAM
‎512 GB
‎No
B09N4ZL8NV
December 6, 2021
```

Comment: I write list because I ask here. And the Indentation is correct in my actual code. I edited my wrong code indentation. The error is from somewhere else

Comment: Would you share the url?

Comment: [https://www.amazon.com/Lenovo-ThinkPad-20W80056US-Touchscreen-Convertible/dp/B09N4ZL8NV/ref=sr_1_3?crid=JGBXK1SFMJ0C&keywords=lenovo+laptop&qid=1656707364&sprefix=lenovo+lapto%2Caps%2C214&sr=8-3] here but its not about that I think.