# how can i fix this encoding issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i think i have a problem with encoding, but i cant find the way to use encode/encoding on that case.
i have this error wehn printing the code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\python\twitter_bot\lesoons\print_tweets.py", line 21, in <module>
    print (tweets)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1255.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1188-1190: character maps to <undefined>
[Finished in 1.5s]
```

```
import tweepy
from api_keys import *


auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
   consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token,access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)





tweets = api.user_timeline(
       screen_name='@elonmusk',
       count=200, 
       include_rts = False,
       tweet_mode = 'extended')


print (tweets)
```

Comment: Provide the full traceback please

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\python\twitter_bot\lesoons\print_tweets.py", line 21, in <module>
    print (tweets)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1255.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1188-1190: character maps to <undefined>
[Finished in 1.5s]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters)

Comment: i have tried  
print (tweets.encode('utf-8') , but its not helping
and i dont want to save it as a file just to print it