# how to fix return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode chaacter '\u2764'

Tags: python

'''

```
def __on_comment(self, video_id, comment):
        self.producer.send('comments', bytes('{}\t{}'.format(video_id, comment), encoding='utf-8'))
        print(video_id, comment)
```

'''

why is it that whenever I run that line of code I get an error

line 17, in __on_comment
print(video_id, comment)
File "C:\Users\Hillary\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2764' in position 0: character maps to 
someone help me on how to fix such an error

Comment: Check this stack : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters?rq=1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.