# 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-translate

When I try to get the Arabic translation from Google translate it show me this:

> 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character maps to

The code is:

```
driver.get("https://translate.google.com/?hl=ar&sl=ar&tl=en&text=%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7&op=translate")
translated_text = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="A3dMNc"]')
sleep(3)
for i in translated_text:
    p=i.get_attribute("data-initial-text")
    print(p.encode('cp850').decode('cp850'))
```

Comment: `'div[class="A3dMNc"]'` matches only 1 element on the page. Why do you need a loop there?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
(presumably you used selenium or its modules ??)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `.encode('cp850').decode('cp850')` part. Just put the below on top of your code ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63573649/10537391)):

```
import sys
sys.stdin.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```