# Failing to install pyautogui on windows in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyautogui

I don't know what is wrong with my PC. When I run python in IDLE, I am able to access it, however, when I move to vs-code, all hell breaks loose.

This is the error I am getting when I try to install it

````
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\file_util.py", line 236, in write_file
          f.write(line + "\n")
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
          return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
      UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 22-23: character maps to <undefined>
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> PyTweening

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.```
````

Comment: Did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters) help?

Comment: How would that page help? It appears to me to be a different matter to mine.

Comment: just [copy the file](https://github.com/asweigart/pytweening/blob/master/pytweening/__init__.py) from github to your project and name it `pytweening.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned my system, literally. I wiped everything, fortunately I had my data backed etc. It appears that I there were conflicts with locally installed dependences. Now I advocate the use of venv to avoid this.