# Get list of files in directory return encode error for persian files name

Tags: python, codec, listdir, cp1252, charmap

When I want to execute simple line of code to get a list of files in one drive i have encountered with encoding error
I have a list of files with persian name. when it comes to list these files name raised an encoding error!

```
import os 
print(os.listdir('D:'))


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 74-76: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: is 'DriveName:' the actual name of the directory?

Comment: no for sure! just suppose it as drive name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import os
files_list = os.listdir(r'D:')
print(files_list)
```

If that doesn't work try using os.walk() instead

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'D:'):
    # select file name
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: still same error: print(os.listdir(r'D:'))
  File "C:\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 74-76: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: can u try getting it into a variable first and print that

Comment: same error with putting the result into a variable

Comment: second solution better work but with this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 2-9: character maps to <undefined>
I have checked it out , my file list include persian file name and when it reached to this point raised an error

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding it as `utf-8`

```
encoded_list = [x.encode("utf-8") for x in os.listdir('DriveName:')]
print(encoded_list)
```

FYI this question has been answered here
[UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters)

Comment: doesn't work on python 3.10.4, AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
as a matter of fact i don't want to read file with special encoding in this step, I've just wanted to get list files in directory.

Comment: FYI this line doesn't work too:  os.listdir(dir, encoding="utf-8")

Comment: Apologies. Fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of visual studio code I have just tried another IDE like jupyter notebook to execute my codes and it works!  it supports persian file names
with the code that mentioned by @No blyat