# Why Django form shows UnicodeEncodeError in Persian language?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have simple form as below:

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import NameForm


def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If I write English character and submit form, it works ok and execute print statement but if I write Persian character like'متن تست' it shows this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /
'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 132-136: character maps to <undefined>
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 4.1.7
Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError
Exception Value:    
'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 132-136: character maps to <undefined>
Exception Location: C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py, line 19, in encode
Raised during:  myapp.views.get_name
Python Executable:  C:\python\test1\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\python\\test1',
 'C:\\python\\test1',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2022.3.2\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_display',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python311',
 'C:\\python\\test1\\venv',
 'C:\\python\\test1\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2022.3.2\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
Server time:    Tue, 14 Mar 2023 19:06:06 +0000

The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: lue="متن تست
```

What should I do?

I tried to use the below link but it didn't help me in Django:

[UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because the character encoding used by your system's console cannot handle the Persian characters. To fix this issue, you can set the default encoding to `UTF-8` in your Django `settings.py` file as:

```py
import sys
import io

sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer, encoding='utf-8')
```

This code sets the default encoding for standard output to **UTF-8**, which can handle **non-ASCII** characters.

Also, the HTML should have the following:

```py
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

This tells the browser to use **UTF-8** encoding for displaying the text.

Additionally, I'd also recommend you make a condition check when the form is not valid, say for example:

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect 

def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return redirect('some_error_page')
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```