# Django-Meta Package for other Languages

Tags: python, django, meta-tags

I have two questions about [Meta](https://django-meta.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) package (for meta tags in templates) of Django and those are : 1.Does this package can support other languages like Persian? 2.If it can support, I just need to change my Language_Code to "fa-IR", or should I consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75737504/why-django-form-shows-unicodeencodeerror-in-persian-language) too? Thanks for your attention.