# localstack 0.12.18 fails to install

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, setuptools, localstack

I am trying to install localstack `0.12.18` on a windows 10 Enterprise machine.

I'm running `Python 3.9.0` and `pip 23.0.1`.

I have downloaded the `.tar.gz` file directly from pypi.org and installing it via:

`pip install C:\Users\me\Downloads\localstack-0.12.18.tar.gz --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org`

This is the output:

```
pip install C:\Users\me\Downloads\localstack-0.12.18.tar.gz --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
Processing c:\users\me\downloads\localstack-0.12.18.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Anaconda\envs\python390\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Anaconda\envs\python390\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Anaconda\envs\python390\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hvz55xsa\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hvz55xsa\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hvz55xsa\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 484, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hvz55xsa\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 54, in <module>
        File "C:\Anaconda\envs\python390\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
          return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 2184: character maps to <undefined>
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Any ideas on what the solution might be?

Thank you

Comment: Most probably some entries in package metadata contain utf-8 characters that are not readable by cp1252. Try passing the locale in the terminal window where you run `pip install`, e.g. start CMD via `cmd.exe /K chcp 65001` and try the `pip install` command from there.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the above solution and received the same error.  After running `cmd.exe /K chcp 65001` a command prompt with the following entry opened `Active code page: 65001`.  When running the `pip install` command I received the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by setting the following environment variable prior to executing the `pip` command:  `setx PYTHONUTF8 1`.  Now the installations go through.

I arrived at this solution through this SO post: [UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters)