PHP proc_open with Python script causes UnicodeEncodeError
I'm trying to run a Python script from a PHP script using proc_open. The Python script works fine when run directly from the command line, but raises a UnicodeEncodeError when run from PHP. I suspect the issue might be related to how the output is captured and handled in PHP, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
I'm working on a project where I need to invoke a Python script from a PHP script. The Python script processes some data and prints the results. Here is the PHP code I'm using:
<?php

function my_shell_exec($cmd, &$stdout=null, &$stderr=null) {
    $proc = proc_open($cmd,[
        1 => ['pipe','w'],
        2 => ['pipe','w'],
    ],$pipes);
    $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    return proc_close($proc);
}

$output = my_shell_exec('.\\.venv\\Scripts\\activate && .\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe infer.py', $stdout, $stderr);
var_dump($output);
var_dump($stdout);
var_dump($stderr);
exit();

Output from PHP:
int(1)
string(183) "Init model
Model already exists in keras-model/model-transventricular-v3.keras, skipping model init.
Infer image
(1, 256, 256, 1)
" keras-model\model-transventricular-v3.keras "
"
string(2416) "2024-06-09 22:57:14.361024: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\path\to\infer.py", line 220, in <module>
    infer_image("input.dat")
  File "D:\path\to\infer.py", line 201, in infer_image
    prediction = model.predict(images)
  File "C:\path\to\python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 19-38: character maps to <undefined>

Direct Command Line Execution (Works Fine):
(.venv) D:\path\to\project>.\.venv\Scripts\activate && .\.venv\Scripts\python.exe infer.py
2024-06-09 22:56:04.593392: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on.
...
Init model
Model already exists in keras-model/model-transventricular-v3.keras, skipping model init.
Infer image
(1, 256, 256, 1)
I0000 00:00:1717948579.475089   18516 service.cc:153]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2024-06-09 22:56:19.530820: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/utils/dump_mlir_util.cc:268] disabling MLIR crash reproducer, set env var `MLIR_CRASH_REPRODUCER_DIRECTORY` to enable.
I0000 00:00:1717948580.392302   18516 device_compiler.h:188] Compiled cluster using XLA!  This line is logged at most once for the lifetime of the process.
1/1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2s 2s/step


Python Script (infer.py):
import os
from keras.models import load_model  # type: ignore
# from keras.optimizers import Adam # type: ignore
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import cv2
import numpy as np
import gdown

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not os.path.exists('input.dat'):
        print("input.dat not exists")
        exit(0)

    print("Init model")
    init_model()

    print("Infer image")
    infer_image("input.dat")

def infer_image(image_filepath):
    # Preprocess image
    images = preproces(image_filepath)
    print(images.shape)

    path = os.path.join('keras-model', 'model-transventricular-v3.keras')
    print('"', path, '"')

    # load model
    model = load_model(path)

    # Predict image
    prediction = model.predict(images)
    predictions = np.argmax(prediction, axis=1)

    # further processing


Dunno what just happened, doing this solution can solved my problem:
if __name__ == '__main__':
  sys.stdin.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
  sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')

  # ...

Output:
int(0)
string(407) "Init model
Model already exists in keras-model/model-transventricular-v3.keras, skipping model init.
Infer image
(1, 256, 256, 1)
" keras-model\model-transventricular-v3.keras "

[1m1/1[0m [32m━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━[0m[37m[0m [1m0s[0m 2s/step
[1m1/1[0m [32m━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━[0m[37m[0m [1m2s[0m 2s/step
"
string(1601) "2024-06-09 23:19:26.963207: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may
see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To
turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-06-09 23:19:27.937896: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly
different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off,
set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-06-09 23:19:29.885933: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to
use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler
flags.
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
I0000 00:00:1717949982.644210 22100 service.cc:145] XLA service 0x2097abd9cb0 initialized for platform Host (this does
not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
I0000 00:00:1717949982.644533 22100 service.cc:153] StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2024-06-09 23:19:42.697126: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/utils/dump_mlir_util.cc:268] disabling MLIR crash
reproducer, set env var `MLIR_CRASH_REPRODUCER_DIRECTORY` to enable.
I0000 00:00:1717949983.623732 22100 device_compiler.h:188] Compiled cluster using XLA! This line is logged at most once
for the lifetime of the process.
"

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63573649/11748924
