fastapi dev fails with UnicodeEncodeError
After installing FastAPI as documented, the command fastapi dev fastapi_app/ fails with

| +-------------------------------- locals
---------------------------------+ | | | final = False                                                           | | | | input = '\U0001f4c1 gpt-oe-rfq-automation'
| | | |  self = <encodings.cp1252.IncrementalEncoder object at
| | | |         0x0000024661D35D50>
| | |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+ |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+ UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character
'\U0001f4c1' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

on git bash in Windows for Python 3.11 and 3.12.
How can this be fixed ?

As documented in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63573649/1587329, this can be fixed by setting
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8

in the shell. Afterwards, the message changes to [...]

┌─ Python package file structure ─┐  │
│  │   src                         │  │  ├──  init.py
│  │  └──  api                     │  │      └──  init.py
│  │                                 │
└─────────────────────────────────┘
INFO     Importing module src.api ERROR    Could not find FastAPI app
in module, try using --app

